# Do gentiles have neshamot?

Tags: gentiles, mysticism-kabbalah, tanya

As I have seen [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/nefesh-neshama-and-ruach-as-words-for-soul/9360#9360), some say that only Jews have a *neshama*, others say that all humans have one. There was a reference there only of the former opinion (Jews only), and I know from elsewhere that that is indeed what the book of Tanya says.

Are there indeed kabbalists (as this meaning of *neshama* is specific to the Kabbala) who hold 
 that all humans have *neshamot*? If yes, is there a specific division (e.g., Sefaradim / Ashkenazim)?

Comment: As Sholom points out in his answer, Tanya does not say that they do not have souls, just that their souls are different.

Comment: The meaning of _neshama_ is specific to Kabbala???

Comment: @DoubleAA, see the link inside the question.

Comment: Funny, I just stumbled across an article on this very topic. The full article isn't online (sorry), but you can see the executive summary: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2016%20Balk.pdf

Comment: Bachrach's article is now available online in full.

Comment: In the beginning of mesechta avoda zara there are a few gentiles mentioned that became deserving of an afterlife in olam haba and I'm not sure how one would understand that if they did not have a neshama

Answer (score 22):

See ["The Soul of a Jew, the Soul of a Non-Jew: Two Views "](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/744571/Rabbi_Hanan_Balk/The_Soul_of_a_Jew,_the_Soul_of_a_Non-Jew%3a__Two_Views)(mp3) by Rabbi Chanan Balk.

Tanya posits that all humans possess a *nefesh bahamit* ("animalistic soul") whereas only Jews possess a *nefesh elokit* ("G-dly soul"), whatever that means. But there are other opinions.

Rabbi Balk consulted several major rabbis, all of them affiliated with the Beth Din of America, regarding the question: "do Jews have entirely different souls than non-Jews?"

- One rabbi replied: "of course, what's the question?"
- Another replied: "Of course not, what are you talking about?"
- A third replied: "Believe it if you like, not if you don't; it's not one of Maimonides' Thirteen Fundamentals."

Comment: There's another option - people obtain souls when they become monotheists - that's always how I've taken the verse in Genesis that talks about the souls that Abraham made.

Comment: The best post I've read. This view would do so much for the bnei Noach movement. Please see my answer as well for some insights from a Chassidic/Tanya perspective. If you read Tanya, Likkutei Amarim Ch.4 and you pick up on the nefesh haAdam, the same things happens within Chassidus, in that non-Jews can receive a nefesh Elokit.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: There is support for your idea in a Zohar Chadash (Margaliyot Hayam on Sanhedrin 105a in note 16 quotes it) that people who discuss the Kabalistic view tend to overlook. The gist of the Zohar is that it is not that important where you came from, because if you do teshuva by believing in one G-d and becoming moral (i.e. The 7 mitzvoth), your soul transforms.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a conflict. Each human has a *neshama*, however, Jews have two *neshamot* - one that all the nations have, and an extra one that only Jews have. Additionally, there is a third *neshama* that only Jews Receive on shabbat.

Comment: That's indeed what Tanya is coming to teach, that the human soul of a Jew and non-Jew is subtly different, due there being a different service required of each.

Answer (score 4):

That answer there is just wrong. It represents that the Lubavitcher Rebbe says that the level of *Neshamah* is not present with non-Jews. In fact, the Lubavitcher Rebbe [says](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/13/31/291) that all 5 levels of Nefesh, Ruach, Neshama, Chaya and Yechida exist in all human souls. The distinction between G-dly and not is precisely in the additional soul (which is what Tanya speaks about - a whole separate one - in other words a divine connection and influence necessitated and determined by the additional Mitzvos required of a Jew over a non-Jew, and the corresponding ability to actualize those requirements).

In other places it speaks about the language of Ger Shenisgair - a *convert* who converts - rather than a non-Jew who converts, that actually the potential for conversion was pre-existing (he was a convert before he actually converted). Thus that very same influence and connection can exist with someone who is currently non-Jewish. My own observation is that this influence is often seen in many conversion stories - a pull and attraction to Judaism that just seems to come out of nowhere.

I think the misunderstanding comes from the fact that *Neshamah* (in the Kabbalistic system) refers primarily to the intellectual capacity of the soul, and the G-dly soul is described as primarily intellectually motivated, thus *Neshamah* can be thought of as being more associated with the G-dly soul. But that is a general association (the *Neshamah* aspect is more predominant in one over the other), not that it doesn't have it.

Comment: Yishai I could not find in that quote from the Rebbe zt"l where he mentioned that gentiles also have all five levels of the Nefesh Elokis

Comment: @Jewels, I never made that claim in the answer.

Comment: @Yishai You most definately did! In the second sentence of the second line of your answer you write "In fact, the Lubavitcher Rebbe says that all 5 levels of Nefesh, Ruach, Neshama, Chaya and Yechida exist in **all human souls**." Do you have a source for this or don't you?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore, you appear to be conflating "Nefesh Elokis" and "all human souls". All five levels exist in both souls. The link in the answer was redone by the site and now only goes to the first page, but the point is explicitly made [further on](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/13/31/295.htm).

Comment: It states in the source only nr"n, NOT chaya and NOT yechida. In fact, the Rebbe brings up very often in his maamarim the fact that the animal soul does NOT have a yechida, something which is stated explicitly in Tanya ("bavua d'bavua leit lehu").

Comment: @Ysiegel See the link in my comment above: "והנה מצד הענין דזה לעומת זה עשה האלקים, הרי כשם שישנו הלעו"ז לנגד הבחינות נפש רוח נשמה, כמו כן ישנו גם הלעו"ז כנגד הבחינות דחי' יחידה". Don't really remember the details here and don't have the time to re-investigate.

Comment: @Yishai You must have attached the wrong link then, because it says no such thing there. So I recommend you study the source as your Morning Chassidus this Thursday or Shabbos and correct any mistakes made (especially in the name of the Rebbe)

Comment: @Ysiegal, I literally just quoted you where it says that.

Comment: Read Shaar Gilgulim iirc Ch 12, all souls are connected to the Chaya and Yechida of Adam

Answer (score 3):

To read more about the Rebbe Schneerson's view that Gentiles do have a neshamah, please see: http://portraitofaleader.blogspot.com/2009/12/soul-of-gentile.html

> I cannot see where there could have been any difference of opinion on this matter, inasmuch as it is explicitly stated in various sources, and statements are also found in various sections of Tanach (Isaiah 42:5, 57:16), to the effect that Gentiles also have a neshama . . . . It seems to me, therefore, that you may have been arguing at cross-purposes, and that perhaps the question related more to the fact that there are different levels and qualities of soul. Now if this was the point of contention, then it is true that the soul of the Gentile and the soul of the Jew differ in their nature, this being connected with one of the basic principles of the Torah – the fact that the Jews are a people chosen from among the nations of the world. This chosen-ness originates in the fact that when G-d was about to give the Torah at Mt. Sinai, He first offered it to all the other nations of the world, who refused to accept it. The Jewish people did accept it. Needless to add, this is in no way inconsistent with the statement of our Sages, to the effect that the righteous among the Gentiles have a special status and, according to the Rambam, also have a share in the World-to-Come.
>
> Judging by your letter, it is surely unnecessary for me to emphasize to you what has already been indicated above, namely, that our belief in the chosen-ness of the Jewish people is not a matter of chauvinism or fanaticism, but rather the deep-felt realization that this uniqueness carries with it great responsibilities and special obligations. This is why, for example, Jews have to fulfill “Taryag (613) mitzvoth,” whereas Gentiles are not obligated to observe kashrut and various other restrictions connected with the idea of holiness, holiness being the essential aspect of the Jewish soul.

Answer (score 1):

Peshat of the pesukim in chumash seem to be saying that. Vayivra Adam B'Tzelem Elokim, or Vayipach B'Apav Nishmas Chayim, are both talkiung about Adam, and Adam was not Jewish. And don't bring me "atem nikra'im adam", as that's a halachic principle, not applicable to the peshat of the text, which is talking about the specific person, Adam. Adam was not Jewish, he was not part of the Brit Sinai, and did not recieve the Torah. Furthermore, all humanity, including non-Jews, descend from him. To say that non-Jews don't have souls at all is to ignore chumash. Additionally, The Gemara in Sanhedrin 37a says "why was man created alone, to tell you that anyone who destroys a life, is as if he destroyed a whole world, and whoever saves a life, is as if he saved a whole world". The girsa that appears in our texts of a life "in Israel" is not in the yerushalmi version of the same mishna, and appears to be incorrect. The message about the importance of an individual's life is clear

Comment: Importance of a life doesn't equate necessarily with having a soul. Can you provide support for your implied claim that it does? Otherwise, the only thing in your answer that's relevant to the question AFAICT is the quote about _nishmas chayim_.

Comment: The quotes about tzelem elokim and nishmat chaim are the main sources. The authors of "Torat Hamelech" who allowed the murder of non-jews, adduced proof from their assertion that there is a qualitative difference between Jewish souls and non-Jewish souls. I do not think that approach works in the sources.

Comment: If Adam has a soul,everyone has a soul.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing a *nefesh elokit*(G-dly soul) with a *nefesh Yehudit*(Jewish soul). I have yet to see a description in Tanya of a nefesh Yehudit. Tanya is describing a *nefesh elokit* (G-dly Soul), a *nefesh haAdam* (human soul), and a *nefesh bahamit* (animalistic soul).

The nefesh haAdam(human soul) which everyone has, if it loses itself completely in the study of Torah and "grasps" Torah as defined by Tanya, then the seichol(intellect, which is the upper 3 attributes/sefirot) grasp the inner essence of G-d and therefore grasp a nefesh Elokit (G-dly soul).

All humans who have the nefesh haAdam(to my knowledge) can grasp a nefesh Elokit. Non-Jews should only grasp their seven mitzvot at first if they so desire, but maybe more to complete the seichel(one should be talking with an orthodox Rabbi at this point). Also, one cannot fully grasp the 613 organs of "the King" as Tanya describes, without fully grasping the 613 mitzvot.

The translations that it's a "Jewish soul" is wrong. It's a G-dly soul, not necessary a Jewish soul that the Tanya describes. All *nefesh Yehudit*(Jewish souls) are *nefesh Elokit*(G-dly souls), but not all *nefesh Elokit*(G-dly souls) are *nefesh Yehudit*(Jewish souls).

Comment: Look at tanya end of chapter 1 beginning of chapter 2 "and the second soul (the G-dly soul" in YISROEL (the jewish people) is a piece of G-d above, literally...""

Comment: @bluejayke and your point?

Comment: just good to put gentiles in their place

Comment: @bluejayke Tanya doesn't address all gentiles, so it sounds like you still have some work to do. The definition of Chasidei Umot haOlam by Lubavitch Chassidus and non-Chassidus sources, are non-Jews who don't unify the name. I have yet to see Torah explicitly mention non-Jews that unify the name properly and provide what type of geder and din such people belong to.

Comment: likutei sichos chalek gimel parshas tzav end-middle of os 4 "...Regaring the nations of the world, its completely not relevant to say [that they could] "sin"--which implies opposite to Hashems will, since they have **completely no connection** to the will of the creator, not even in an exclusive way [to say that they went against it] sincebecause they have no connection with the Will, they're not commanded on the commandments of a Jew [paraenthesis in original:] (since the 7 mitzvos bnei noach are an entirely different category {in note 15: "therefore, their fulfillment doesn't require ol..."

Answer (score 0):

shaarei kedusha part 3 shaar 2 brings the distinction basically he says the soul of a jew is connected with the mystical worlds while the soul of a non jew is not.

> Afterwards, the Jewish man was created. Purer in all the soul levels
>   than all other creations, whether in the souls of Domem (earth),
>   Tzomeach (water), Chaya (wind) or Medaber (Fire).
>
> In being more pure than all the creations, he is elevated even higher
>   because he is also included and tied in with all the 5 worlds and in
>   all their details. How? After the lower soul, a soul enters him from
>   the firmament of Vilon, and from there and above, all the way up to
>   the highest firmament in Asiya, all this together is called the soul
>   of Asiya. This is called the Intellectual soul, the holy soul in a
>   person. It is divided into the 5 soul levels...

Comment: I don't see in the quote brought here where the distinction is made between the Jewish and Gentile soul.

Comment: @Jewels see it in context

Answer (score 0):

The baal hatanya explains that gentiles have animal souls, whereas Jews have both animal and godly souls.

However, some non-Jews who are especially righteous have a godly soul too IIRC.

Comment: Would you happen to have a citation for the righteous non-Jewish soul? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It's in one of the first few chapters of tanya (might he a Footnote in the version I'm using)...I'll try to find it at some point.

Comment: @EhevuTov Its in the notes of the Tzemach Tzedek to the end of chapter 1 tanya