# What does Judaism say about pets in the World to Come?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, animals, afterlife

What does Judaism teach about animals in the World to Come? Pets hold such a beloved place in the now and appear, more than [other animals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36007/do-animals-have-an-afterlife), to have there own will in their actions. Is there hope that we will see them in the afterlife?

Comment: I hope this helps http://www.aish.com/atr/Animal_Souls.html