# David had the Holy Spirit. Can any jew have it too?

Tags: king-david

> > "Cast me not away from Your presence; and take not Your **holy spirit** from me."
> >     Psalms 51:11
> >     "(51:13) <<

According to this  [post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56325/inner-being-soul-or-spirit), our Creator gives us a [Yechidah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56325/inner-being-soul-or-spirit) at the time of conception, which (I guess) is not the same holy spirit that David is referring to in his psalm?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you try to add some detail to your question, to better enable people to give you a proper answer? You have up to 30,000 characters to use in the body of the post, which is currently just a quote.

Comment: @Manuel Milla You are correct, the subject of "Yechidah" is not the same thing as what you call "holy spirit". In fact, they are completely different subjects and your 2nd paragraph should be removed. This question needs to be developed to better express what you are inquiring about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Midrash says,

> Whoever teaches the Torah in public partakes of the Holy Spirit (Cant. R. i. 9, end; comp. Lev. R. xxxv. 7).

Rabbi Phinehas ben Yair said:

> Holiness leads to humility; humility leads to the fear of sin, the fear of sin leads to saintliness; saintliness leads to the Holy Spirit.'

Tan. Wayechi, 14 says,

> The pious act through the Holy Spirit.

These sources thus make it clear that one can have Ruach ha-Qodesh (the Holy Spirit or the spirit of holiness) as David had.

**Bibliography**: *Jewish Encyclopedia*, 'HOLY SPİRİT'.

---

Comment: I can't speak for whoever downvoted, but part of the problem with both the question and your answer is at least partially related to who "We" is referring to. "Ruach Hakodesh" is one of the levels of prophecy as taught in the Torah. As a consequence of the problems with Bilaam, Moshe specifically asked of G-d not to give gentiles further access to prophecy. According to the view of most, that request was granted.

Comment: @Yaakov Deane The sources quoted refer to Jews and not Gentiles, and are all Jewish sources.

Comment: I understand, but neither the question, nor your answer are clarifying that. An undifferentiated "we" means 'all of us', Jews and non-Jews. Both you and Manuel (at least in the context of his posts on the Christianity stack) are non-Jews. So based upon your answer, without clarification, it would be incorrect according to traditional Jewish teaching.

Comment: @Yaacov Deane  Where is it written in the Torah that Moshe requested God not to give the Gentiles the spirit of holiness and the spirit of prophecy?

Comment: This is stated in tractate Brachot 7a by Rabbi Yochanan in the name of Rabbi Yossi based up Moshe's request of G-d in Shemot 33:16. And G-d's granting of Moshe's request is found in 33:17. The statement from Brachot also follows the view of Rashi.